# Can you address people in the same family by the first and last name of the patriach?

Tags: kinship-terms

If you have "*Jane and John Smith and their kids*," and John's brother's family made up of "*Mai and Bruce Smith and their kids*," and you want to distinguish which of the Smith families you are talking about, can you say:

> The John Smiths?

Comment: This is certainly done.

Comment: Doubtless some people who prefer _Jane and John Smith and their kids_  will prefer to use _the Jane Smiths_.

Comment: There is no single way this is done among English-speakers; it depends as much on the families and the individuals as anything else. In my family, it's always been easier to use geography: *Is Minnesota auntie coming for Thanksgiving? Are the Toronto cousins coming to the wedding?*

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I certainly am guided by your answers.

Comment: @choster And, of course, the less common than it used to be "Oh Jane Smythe, is she one of the Chorlton-cum-Hardy Smythes?"